# linear independence of $\sin(k \pi / m)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory

I have tried searching the literature for a result like the following, but have not found anything.

For a positive integer $m$, is it known that
$$\{ \sin (k \pi / m): 1 \leq k \leq m/2, (k,m)=1 \}$$
is linearly independent over the rationals?

References or a proof would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I had an answer which claimed linear independence, but Vladimir Dotsenko explained it was fallacious (so it's been deleted). However, in conjunction with his remarks, the answer shows the result is true if $2m$ is square-free, if this is of any interest.

Comment: Why not put that back as an answer? Combined with the other counterexample, it seems to provide a more useful answer to the question and improve the body of knowledge

Comment: @RichardRast Thanks for the encouragement.

Comment: thanks to all for your answers. Both the counterexamples and Todd Trimble's proof for 2m square-free are really helpful and appreciated!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Note: Fedor and Vladimir have already answered the question, but this is a partial answer in the other direction, under a stronger hypothesis. (This answer, which I had earlier deleted, has been edited in response to some helpful comments.)

If $m$ is odd and square-free, then the claim of the OP holds.

Let $S$ be the set $\{k: 1 \leq k \leq m/2, (k, m) = 1\}$. If $\sum_{k \in S} a_k \sin(k\pi/m) = 0$ for some rationals $a_k$, then

$$\sum_{k \in S} a_k(e^{k\pi i/m} - e^{-k\pi i/m}) = 0.$$

Here $N = 2m$ is square-free, and in that case the primitive $N$-th roots of unity are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$ (see this mathstackexchange discussion: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87290/basis-of-primitive-nth-roots-in-a-cyclotomic-extension).

For $N = 2m$, any odd $k \in S$ is prime to $N$ and hence $e^{k \pi i/m}, e^{-k\pi i/m}$ are primitive $N$-th roots of unity. If $k \in S$ is even, then $m + k$ is odd and prime to $m$ and thus to $N$, so $e^{(m + k)\pi i/m} = -e^{k\pi i/m}$ is also primitive $N$-th root of unity, as is its conjugate $e^{(m - k)\pi i/m}$; notice the $m-k$ lie in $\{j: m/2 \leq j \leq m, \gcd(j,m) = 1\}$ which is disjoint from $S$. Then

$$\begin{array}{lll}
\sum_{k \in S} a_k(e^{k\pi i/m} - e^{-k\pi i/m}) & = & \sum_{\text{odd}\; k \in S} a_k(e^{k\pi i/m} - e^{-k\pi i/m}) + \sum_{\text{even}\; k \in S} a_k(e^{k\pi i/m} - e^{-k\pi i/m}) \\ 
& = & \sum_{\text{odd}\; k \in S} a_k(e^{k\pi i/m} - e^{-k\pi i/m}) + \sum_{\text{even}\; k \in S} a_k(e^{(m-k)\pi i/m} - e^{-(m-k)\pi i/m})
\end{array}$$

where all the primitive roots of unity appearing in the last expression are manifestly distinct. By linear independence of the primitive roots, if that linear combination is zero, then $a_k = 0$ for all $k$, as required.

Comment: Dear Todd, this is confusing. Primitive roots of unity only form a basis for a square-free $N$. (See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87290/basis-of-primitive-nth-roots-in-a-cyclotomic-extension for instance.)

Comment: @VladimirDotsenko Basis or not, don't we still have linear independence? I'm not seeing anything in Lang speaking against this, although maybe I'm overlooking something (?).

Comment: The number of primitive roots is equal to the degree of the extension so they are linearly independent if and only if they form a basis. For example, for $N=4$ the two primitive roots are $i$ and $-i$.

Comment: $\exp(\pm k\pi i/m)$ is primitive $2m$-th root of unity only if $k$ is odd. That would be OK if $m$ was even, but then $N$ wouldn't be squarefree.

Comment: @JarekKuben You are quite right; thank you very much. I have fixed the error.

Answer (score 22):

$$\sin \frac{5\pi}{36}+\sin \frac{7\pi}{36}-\sin \frac{17\pi}{36}=0.$$
This may be otained by multiplying $2\sin\frac{\pi}6-1=0$ by $\cos \frac{\pi}{36}$.

Comment: How do you come up with this?

Comment: @Nik at first, I started from 'almost counterexample' $2\sin\pi/6-\sin\pi/2=0$, which we all know from childhood. Then a natural idea to make a genuine counterexample is multiplying by some cosine and using $2\cos a\sin b=\sin(b+a)+\sin(b-a)$. Coprimality condition is easily examined.

Comment: by the way, multiplying by $\cos \frac\pi{18}$ we get Vladimir's example

Answer (score 13):

We have 
$$\sin\frac{\pi}{9}+\sin\frac{2\pi}9-\sin\frac{4\pi}9=\sin\frac{2\pi}{18}+\sin\frac{4\pi}{18}-\sin\frac{8\pi}{18}=\sin\frac{2\pi}{18}-\sin\frac{8\pi}{18}+\sin\frac{14\pi}{18},$$
and the latter, denoting $\xi_{18}=\exp\frac{2\pi i}{18}$, is the imaginary part of $$\xi_{18}-\xi_{18}^4+\xi_{18}^7=\xi_{18}(1-\xi_{18}^3+\xi_{18}^6)=0.$$
Thus, your conjecture is wrong.